# Paso de Datos entre Formularios WPF

Tags: wpf

tengo la siguiente duda, tengo un formulario con un datagrid con el cual pretendo que al seleccionar la fila del datagrid, poder mandar la información del datagrid a un nuevo formulario y presentar dicha información en los correspondientes textbox de la ventana Nueva Estoy usando WPF Agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow Español**. Te recomiendo que te pases por la página de [ask]. Para que tengas mayor probabilidad de que contesten tu pregunta explica más a detalle tu problema y lo que has intentado.

Comment: El origen de datos del DataGrid es una DataTable o una colección?

Comment: uso una coleccion `datos = _clientsBOl.GetAll();
                DgvClients.ItemsSource = datos;`

Answer (score 0):

usa la propiedad binding, te dejo aqui un ejemplo:

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="dgSells" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="267" Width="632" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" Cursor="Hand" 
                                        IsReadOnly="True" Background="White" SelectedIndex="0" VerticalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}" AlternationCount="2" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFD7D8B9" BorderThickness="1" Foreground="Black" HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding VentaID}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="VentaID" Width="85"/>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Fecha, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yy\}}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Fecha" Width="85"/>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NombreProducto}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="No. Parte" Width="190"/>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrdenCompra}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Órden compra" Width="120"/>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Cantidad}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Cantidad" Width="70"/>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PrecioPO}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Precio OC" Width="91.5"/>

                                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                                </DataGrid>

     <TextBox x:Name="VentaID" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.VentaID, ElementName=dgSells, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="661,114,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="169" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

De esta manera el textbox tomara el valor ventaID de la fila seleccionada.
Ahora si tus campos textbox estan en una ventana nueva deberas hacer paso de parámetros a la ventana nueva, lo puedes hacer usando textboxes escondidas que estén conectadas al datagrid mediante la propiedad binding para luego usar ese texto para hacer el paso de parámetros

Comment: lo que pretendo es que al darle click al datagrid, me abra un nuevo formulario cargando la info de la fila seleccionada. mas o menos como le tendria que hacer ?

Comment: Hola, es muy sencillo el datagrid view tiene un evento que se llama mousedoubleclick, crealo de modo que al hacer doble click entre a dicho evento, dentro de este evento deberás obtener los valores de la fila seleccionada, lo puedes hacer de varias formas, eso dependerá de como hayas cargado la información al data grid, al desconocer esto no te podría decir cual puedes usar exactamente pero puedes usar el binding en textbox ocultas, luego al llamar a tu ventana nueva con su paso de parámetros. envíame tu proyecto especificando donde deseas hacer esto y te ayudo, bryan.garcia.duran@gmail.com

Comment: ya lo resolvi muchas gracias lo que hice fue lo siguiente. utilice una clase statica a ella le mande los datos del item seleccionado del datagrid, al abrir el nuevo formulario simplemente llene los datos con un query usando el id del datagrid. muchas **Gracias**!!

Comment: Ahora quiero que el cerrar el segundo formulario me actualiza el datagrid a los datos que modifique me podrías apoyar.